# Can I create my personal Raspberry Pi OS and put it into GitHub?

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, raspberry-pi3

I want make this(link) but with Raspberry Pi OS (not Arch Linux) but I don't know what to do.
https://disconnected.systems/blog/custom-rpi-image-with-github-travis/#github-repository
Can anyone explain me how you do this?
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Just upload your .iso or .img file to a repository on github and feel free to add the source code if you want. You can share the link of the repo so we can try the OS! <3

Comment: I don't understand the procedure explained by the link I posted and would like a more accurate explanation of how to do the job.You said something that I believe is not possible to do on GitHub. Thank you so much